# Lost connection to MySQLserver

Tags: python, mysql, django

I try to run my app django but I get this error

```
 super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2013, "Lost connection to MySQL server at 'handshake: reading inital communication packet', syste
m error: 10061")
```

my databases is declared as

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'sdms_tracker',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'anna',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '82',
        'OPTIONS': {"init_command": "SET storage_engine=MyISAM"},
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, are you able to login into with `mysql -u root -p fadma -h localhost` or `mysql -uroot -pfadma -hlocalhost` ?

Comment: I did not understand your question?

Comment: I log in directly in the page web of phpmyadmin

Comment: I imagine that you installed the MySQL server (database) on your machine. With MySQL comes the CLI (Command Line Interface) command that allows to interact with Servers (in your case the MySQL that is running on your localhost). Are you using Linux?

Comment: And are you sure that PORT `82` is correct? The default port for MySQL is `3306`.

Comment: No windows,  yes because I get database when I run XAMPP in http://localhost:82/phpmyadmin/

Comment: Anna - When you are connecting to `localhost:82/phpmyadmin ` you are connecting to HTTP server (Web server) that serves phpmyadmin. Could you try change port to 3306 please?

Comment: I am able to login with mysql -u root -p anna -h localhost, but when I key my password I get ERROR 1045 (28000): AccŠs refus‚ pour l'utilisateur: 'root'@'@localhost' (mot de passe: OUI)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know French much :). Still it proves that database is running on standard port 3306 :). Are you able to take connection credentials (to database) from phpmyadmin? Does your Django application works after change port to 3306?

Comment: you mean changing the port in phpmyadmin?

Comment: No I mean changing the database settings in Django application from `'PORT': '82',` to  `'PORT': '3306,`. This is original question.

Comment: it is work thank you

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with Django configuration. MySQL port that was set to

```
'PORT': '82'
```

Instead of

```
'PORT': '3306
```